# Need some help to design a custom carousel component in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, swipe

I have to design a "carousel" component for my iOS (Swift) app, like below.

I guess it's kind of `UICollectionView` or `UIPageViewController`, but I haven't any ideas how to implement this. The swipe gesture must bring the next slide to front by disappearing the previous one.

[image: carousel wireframe]

Comment: that's a quite complex interaction and I'm very sure UICollectionView or UIPageViewController are not enough for achieving it. How do you want the visible view to disappear? Should it move to the left, somehow similar to how the app switcher works when double tapping home button?

Comment: Hey @andrei, thanks. Indeed it must move to the left with a cross dissolve animation, and scale up the next one.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you use a scrollView with pagingEnabled = true. You set a delegate to capture didScroll events and use the contentOffset.x value to scale and fade your views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @andrei, I made my component using `pagingEnabled = true`.